# What is the best way to get a list of attached scanners (twain devices) to the computer using C++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, firebreath

I am trying to get a list of attached scanners to my computer using C++, I am developing a browser plugin using Firebreath framework which allows the user to see the list and choose which scanner to use.

My question is: **what is the best way** to get a list of attached scanners (twain devices) to the computer?

Comment: TWAIN API, or the modern WPD API. I'm not sure if scanners support WPD, but if they do - that's the way to go.

Comment: The usualy way to search for the best way is to search for a viable way and then improve. Do you already have a viable way? Also, there is the possibilty that the best way does not exist and every way lacks certain features that are essential to at least some users. What features are important to you?

Comment: The only feature is to find out Online-devices, i actually still don't have a viable way, the only thing i was able to do is get list of printers, but not scanners.

Answer (score 0):

Scanners are most likely going to use TWAIN.  A quick google search turns up this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/296/A-C-Wrapper-for-TWAIN

I'd start there and see what you can find.